# Best Practice to detect whether a point is inside a 2D polygon (vertices of polygon are on a table )

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, spatial

I have a table in a database , where I keep the vertices of polygons , with the following structure : IdPolygon (int) , Latitude (real) , Longitude (real) .

To check if a point is inside one of the registered polygons , I'm looking for the ' IdPolygon ' for a range of latitude and longitude, and then I loop this list of polygons to see if the point is inside any of them .

What is the best practice, with better performance , for me to check if a point is inside any of the polygons registered in the bank?

Comment: You might want to research search algorithms and find one that suites your needs.

Comment: Actually, the list of vertices is not sufficient information.  You need to know in what order they connect to one another.  Otherwise, for instance, you can't tell a regular pentagon from a pentagram (it's possible to construct either from the same set of vertices).  If you have a sequence of vertices, you can use the winding number algorithm to determine if a point is within the polygon.

Comment: Thanks @JuanTomas. The vertices are ordered after your tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you store spatial data using spatial type support by sql server e.g. geometry, geospatial. It does have support indexing and spatial query. See more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933991.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I'll change the data type and the initial strategy.